# Need some explanation about prepared statements in PHP

Tags: php, prepared-statement

Reading this page http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

I got some questions about PS

- In examples i don't see `$stmt = $db->stmt_init();` Is it required to create new instance (
  add `$stmt=$db->stmt_init()` line) at the beginning of the every
  statement and $stmt->close at the end or it doesn't matter at all: I
  can start from `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("...` ??
- Can I create statement object 1 time at the beginning of the code and
  use it all code long?

Comment: You can just do a `->prepare()` call. it'll do a stmt_init for you internally. You should `->prepare()` a new statement for every different query you're running.

Comment: do I need to cloase it after operation?

Comment: Only if you're doing a long-running script. php has fairly good cleanup and will destroy any leftover cruft when functions return and/or the script exits.

Comment: @MarcB can we chat with you? I got some questions about ps.

Comment: @MarcB http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4840/php-ps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `mysqli_prepare()` creates an object with the link identifier and the query you want to run, you don't need to use `mysqli_stmt::init`.

The advantage of using `mysqli_stmt::init` is to create an instance of the object in a config file for example. Any subsequently required / included scripts will have a query object ready for use, reducing the amount of code you need to write.

Second question: Yes. Think of the object as having a lifecycle from the line of code it is initialised to the last line of code of the script OR when its `__destruct()` magic method is called. It can be used at anytime once created allowing you to constantly change the query and execute more code with the same object.

As a note: you must always use `mysqli_stmt::close` after each query (once you have taken the results). This clears the objects query and result sets, re-initialising the object to the same state it would have been in when first created.

Hope that helps.